# Change <select> tag value when it required or not

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

I use a my-select.component in form component.

```
<div *ngIf="items?.length">
  <select [ngModel]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I need to display when call this on form component as `<my-select required></my-select>` set the default value as --select--. otherwise `<my-select></my-select>` --none--.
 How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My Answer:

```
<div *ngIf="items?.length">
  <select [ngModel]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
    <option value="select" selected>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```